# How to persist a class and data across multiple intents and orientation changes

Tags: java, android, android-intent

**Background**

I am currently writing an android app and have run into something i cant quite figure out.

I have 3 `Intent`'s, the main start up intent, an intent that shows live gps and accelerometer data, and an intent that shows a summery of the collected gps and accelerometer data.

The problem i am having is when i switch orientation, the intent is recreated to display in the different orientation thus calling the constructor, `onCreate`, `onStart` and `onResume` causing my internal variables to be reset, or re instantiated and registered with the GPS/Sensor apis causing a lot of bad data.

I do not want to lock the screen orientation, as this would just be a hack fix and not a real fix to solve the problem properly.

I have attempted creating a service by overloading `IntentService`, but this is as far as i got before i stopped understanding how android operates its services, and if a service in android is actually what a service is everywhere else.

**First (bad) attempt**

```
public class GPSLoggingService extends IntentService {

public GPSLoggingService() {
    super("GPSLoggingService");

}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent wi) {
```

**Question**

How would i go about having a class that exists in the same way that allows me to move timing, GPS and sensor logging to a background service and use an api from that service from the intent's to display the data, and have the data be left alone on orientation changes and possibly the intent being hidden and brought back to the foreground.

How would i have this service run automatically on app launch and persist until the app is closed. How would i create an api within this service? do i simply create methods within the service and call those from my intent? or is there a messaging system i must use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea of using a service is correct, and I do recommend reading through [googles documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) as it is pretty good.  What you are looking for in the end is a **Bound Service** which you should bind to you Application context rather than an Activities context.  For example

```
public class BoundService extends Service {
    private final BackgroundBinder _binder = new BackgroundBinder();

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return _binder;
    }


    public class BackgroundBinder extends Binder {
        public BoundService getService() {
            return BoundService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class BoundServiceUser extends Activity {
    private BoundService _boundService;
    private boolean _isBound;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        //The background Service initialization settings
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BoundService.class);
        bindService(intent, _serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (_isBound)
            unbindService(_serviceConnection);
    }

    private ServiceConnection _serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            BoundService.BackgroundBinder binder = (BoundService.BackgroundBinder)service;
            _boundService = binder.getService();
            _isBound = true;

            //Any other setup you want to call. ex.
            //_boundService.methodName();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            _isBound = false;
        }
    };
}
```

I have bound the service to my Activity context for the example; since you want the service to start and stop with your application you will want to extent the Application class to bind and start your service.

If you store the Service as a public variable (or use a getter) then you should be able to access it as a singleton (I'm not a huge fan of singletons but it is best suited for this type of problem).  From there you can access your methods in the service like any other class.

If you have any issues that need to be clarified let me know.

Comment: what would be a clean way of shutting down the service when the app goes away (back button or home button, or switch to another app)?

Comment: Off the top of my head:
Since Application doesn't have an onDestroy method you can try keeping an activity count in the Service. -> When an Activity is started increment, in the Activities onDestroy decrement.  When the count reaches 0 then unbind.  I'm pretty sure I have a better method somewhere but I'm not in a position to look right now.